# OOP PHP: Calling classes as functions after creating an instance of them

Tags: php, php-7.1

What I would like to do after creating an instance of a class is to be able to call the name of that instance as a function.  For example, consider the following class Foo:

```
$bar = new Foo(5); // generates 5 random ints between 0-100
bar(3); // get the third int in the object bar
```

Is this even possible in PHP or would it involve messing with the parser? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Do you mean you want to load properties of that object?

Comment: What you are asking is not clear.

Comment: @john-conde if I want to extend a default PHP class

Comment: So write a class that extends whichever class you are talking about

Comment: yes which i can then call as a function in the name of the instance i make it into

Comment: was the question too vague?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What this question is really about is creating a PHP functor and here's an example I lifted from [here](https://dzone.com/articles/reuse-your-closures-functors):

```
<?php

class SquareCallback
{
    public function __invoke($value)
    {
        return $value * $value;
    }
}

$squareObject = new SquareCallback;
var_dump($squareObject(3));
```